# internal stylesheet with media attribute

Tags: css, internal

I'm trying to use the media attribute for internal style sheet. I am using `media=print` and `media=handheld` for mobile devices. However this is not working. Not to sure why?

EDIT: The outcome I am trying to get is, media="print, test text = blue and picture to be static. Media="handheld" , test text= red and picture to be responsive/dynamic.

```
<html>
 <head>
<style media="print">

p.slide {
width:1040 px;
height:383 px;
color:#00F;
}

</style>
<style media="handheld">
p.slide {
width:20%;
height:10%;
color:#F00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <p class="slide">
     test
        <img src="https://hpva2w-ch3301.files.1drv.com/y4m3P0wDLAI8GVZl1qYwcsqB9AFNfl5mJCFQw_f3627uFXESiPUbkJmyrLNvzVaz4uIIA8vlEX3i11Frkm8p8VGDSwyW8Oempo79nFvc2xFJe5KuKOpVT6ZhNUSasTvPRfX7PBsdL6riiJf8aaSs7McYyZSc9gL0qQZPJEXAk3fjlV93b3bpoxtCBglvXHIQut7RTaM12d0vcrbEvzv-DtQ8A?width=1024&height=683&cropmode=none" >

    </p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, but you can't test "print" and "handheld" on jsfiddle. (It doesn't accept media-attributes, and you can't define `<style media="">` inside the CSS-field.

```html
<html>
 <head>
<style media="print">

p.slide {
width:1040 px;
height:383 px;
color:#00F;
}

</style>
<style media="handheld">
p.slide {
width:20%;
height:10%;
color:#F00;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>

    <p class="slide">
     test
        <img src="https://hpva2w-ch3301.files.1drv.com/y4m3P0wDLAI8GVZl1qYwcsqB9AFNfl5mJCFQw_f3627uFXESiPUbkJmyrLNvzVaz4uIIA8vlEX3i11Frkm8p8VGDSwyW8Oempo79nFvc2xFJe5KuKOpVT6ZhNUSasTvPRfX7PBsdL6riiJf8aaSs7McYyZSc9gL0qQZPJEXAk3fjlV93b3bpoxtCBglvXHIQut7RTaM12d0vcrbEvzv-DtQ8A?width=1024&height=683&cropmode=none" >

    </p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am confused on how this runs fine? Media="print" I want the text "test" font color to be blue which its not. Only thing right is the picture size is static, which it is with the pixel attribute. However media="handheld", the text "test" is not  red and the picture size is not dynamic/responsive, I assumed this what the point of the internal style @media attribute?

Comment: The blue text works here. The example is very limited, but it shows blue text when I try to preview "print to PDF" on my laptop, and black when I just view the page. I can't connect a handheld device to the laptop-development computer, so I can't really test the "handheld" modifier, but I wouldn't rely on it - it's not widely supported, for instance, iPhones does not report as "handheld" - it reports as "screen".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think what  want is screen.

Comment: Screen is the default, but you should use media="screen, tv, projection" as that will basically target all screen that your page should possibly be viewed on.